# How to make CSS Slider to autoplay

Tags: html, css, slider, autoplay

I have this simple HTML/CSS slider with only 2 slides.
I need to make it autoplay the slides every 7 seconds.
I am not familiar with jquery or javascript, so it would be easier for me to implement a css solution...

Can you help?

You can see it in action right now at 
http://www.hotelgalatas.com/test/

Thanks!

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}


/* Slider wrapper*/

.css-slider-wrapper {
  display: block;
  background: #FFF;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}


/* Slider */

.slider {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #ccc;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 0;
  display: flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  -webkit-flex-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1600ms;
  transition: -webkit-transform 1600ms, transform 1600ms;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
}


/* each slide background color */

.slide1 {
  background: #00bcd7;
  left: 0;
}

.slide2 {
  background: #009788;
  left: 100%;
}

.slider>div {
  text-align: center;
}


/* Slider inner slide effect */

.slider h2 {
  color: #FFF;
  font-weight: 900;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 45px;
  line-height: 120%;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(500px);
  transform: translateX(500px);
}

.slider .button {
  color: #FFF;
  padding: 5px 30px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  text-decoration: none;
  opacity: 0;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-500px);
  transform: translateX(-500px);
}

.slider h2,
.slider .button {
  -webkit-transition: opacity 800ms, -webkit-transform 800ms;
  transition: transform 800ms, opacity 800ms;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 1s;
  /* Safari */
  transition-delay: 1s;
}


/* Next and Prev arrows */

.control {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-top: -25px;
  z-index: 55;
}

.control label {
  z-index: 0;
  display: none;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: #FFF;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0.2;
}

.control label:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.next {
  right: 1%;
}

.previous {
  left: 1%;
}


/* Slider Pager */

.slider-pagination {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 1000;
}

.slider-pagination label {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  margin: 0 2px;
  border: solid 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* Slider Pager arrow event */

.slide-radio1:checked~.next .numb2,
.slide-radio2:checked~.previous .numb1 {
  display: block;
  z-index: 1
}


/* Slider Pager event */

.slide-radio1:checked~.slider-pagination .page1,
.slide-radio2:checked~.slider-pagination .page2 {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)
}


/* Slider slide effect */

.slide-radio1:checked~.slider {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0%);
  transform: translateX(0%);
}

.slide-radio2:checked~.slider {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}

.slide-radio1:checked~.slide1 h2,
.slide-radio2:checked~.slide2 h2,
.slide-radio1:checked~.slide1 .button,
.slide-radio2:checked~.slide2 .button {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
  transform: translateX(0);
  opacity: 1
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .slider h2 {
    font-size: 20px;
  }
  .slider>div {
    padding: 0 2%
  }
  .control label {
    font-size: 35px;
  }
  .slider .button {
    padding: 0 15px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="css-slider-wrapper">
  <input type="radio" name="slider" class="slide-radio1" checked id="slider_1">
  <input type="radio" name="slider" class="slide-radio2" id="slider_2">
  <div class="slider-pagination">
    <label for="slider_1" class="page1"></label>
    <label for="slider_2" class="page2"></label>
  </div>
  <div class="next control">
    <label for="slider_1" class="numb1"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i>
</label>
    <label for="slider_2" class="numb2"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i>
</label>
  </div>
  <div class="previous control">
    <label for="slider_1" class="numb1"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-left"></i>
</label>
    <label for="slider_2" class="numb2"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-left"></i>
</label>
  </div>
  <div class="slider slide1">
    <div>
      <h2>First Slide Text</h2>
      <a href="#" class="button">Button1</a> <a href="#" class="button">Button2</a> </div>
  </div>
  <div class="slider slide2">
    <div>
      <h2>Second Slide Text</h2>
      <a href="#" class="button">Button1</a> <a href="#" class="button">Button2</a> </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

to deal with time you have to use javascript/jquery.

you can access the slides by using class names and add/hide the elements every 7 seconds and use them with setInterval function.

```
var interval = setInterval(function () {document.getElementById('previous-control').addClass('hide'); document.getElementById('next-control').addClass('show'); }, 7000);
```

where you have to add the hide and show classes in css with display none and block

Comment: Thank you Avinash for your tip,

However, since i am not familiar with javascript at all, can i ask you:

- I assume that I have to make a separate js file with the above code (ie autoplay.js). How do i call the js? within html?

- I understand that i also have to hide/show the elements slide1, slide2 and also their text and nav buttons using css.

can you please guide me to this?
thank you

Comment: yes you have to create a new js file and use script tag to use that javascript file in your html code